# Prevent hardware and library examples from showing in the Sketchbook menu

Tags: arduino-ide

I have various subdirectories in `{SKETCHBOOK}/hardware/` and `{SKETCHBOOK}/libraries/` that contain an `examples/` subdirectory. These examples are showing up in `File` | `Sketchbook` | `hardware` and `File` | `Sketchbook` | `libraries`. Is there any way I can prevent them from showing up in that menu without moving them under the system-level Arduino directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [code](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/2c05841588313918a3fcab7ecbc01023a8621f6f/app/src/processing/app/Base.java#L1618) it is scanning all folders and there is no option to change that behavior. Also looking at the code, it looks like it dumps them into a sub-menu, hiding them away a little further, if the folder is named anything except "examples", which could be an alternative option for you.

The final option would be to fork your own version and come up with some exclusion logic, maybe with some kind of ".ignore" kind of logic where you can specify folders to exclude form the menu.

Comment: Interesting. I think that the proper fix would be to modify `Base.addSketches(JMenu, File)` to skip "important" directories, since there shouldn't be user sketches in there regardless. But thank you for pointing this out,